# Rails views-table to display value from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, html-table, view

I have a `<table>` in a view but it's showing username from another model -`Profile`. I'm calling Profile for each row of table. There are two problems with this: exposing my model in view by calling it & each time calling Profile which is inefficient.

Is there a way to access all usernames in controller first with one SQL query and then display only each value in table correspondingly or a better approach to show values without table?

```
           <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th> Applicant Name </th>
              <th> Email </th>
              <th> Documents </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <% employee.eager_load(:application).each do |e_application| %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= Profile.find_by_user_id(e_application.user_id).full_name %></td>
                  <td><%= mail_to(e_application.applicant.email) %></td>
                  <td><%= link_to e_application.doc.file.basename, e_application.doc_url if !eapplication.doc.file.nil? %></td>  
                </tr>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Many thanks. I'm new to rails and not found any example.

Answer (score 1):

For start don`t do

```
Profile.find_by_user_id(e_application.user_id).full_name
```

If you did relations correctly just call

```
e_application.user.full_name
```

In case you don`t always have user

```
e_application.try(&:user).try(&:full_name)
```

use this so you don`t get error.

Single dot notations is always good but for this example no need to complicate things.

Comment: thanks Sedad. but user table doesnot have full_name and only profile table has full_name. To get username for each application, e_application.user will  not help. can I collect all usernames in profile array and then map it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, include the `profile` table in the employee list.

For eg.

I am assuming that

employee

```
 belongs_to :user
```

user

```
 has_one :profile
```

then,

```
employee = Employee.includes(user: [:profile], :application).where(your condition)
```

then simply display as below:

```
 <% employee.each do |e_application| %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= e_application.user.profile.full_name %></td>
```

Comment: Thx, Chakreshwar but I didnot follow how to include profile in user...employee is an enum role in user.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to somehow get all full_name from profile using a where query in an array or a hash in e_application controller and use that array/hash to map it to each table row. And when I display I will have to map that hash value for a table row using user_id as key. The part to display looks complex to fetch from hash. any ideas